# Where is the memcached configuration file in archlinux?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration

I can't find a configuration file for memcached (1.4.21-1) on archlinux. I have looked in /etc/ and /etc/conf.d/ . Is there a config file? And where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memcached doesn't have a configuration file on Arch anymore since [May 2013](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/memcached&id=93dcd1ae239de5142f6497f15a0f21cc3af10567).

Answer (score 9):

As pointed out by Wieland, the `/etc/conf.d/memcached` file was removed when the package was changed to use a systemd unit. The `/etc/conf.d` directory was used by SysVinit, and hence no longer applicable.

The options for the service can be edited by editing the systemd unit. The recommended way to do this is to run `systemctl edit memcached.service --full`. This will copy `/usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/memcached.service` and open an editor for the latter file.

You probably only want to change the `ExecStart=` setting. E.g if you wanted to memcached to listen on a unix port, you make the following change:

```
--- /usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service   2015-01-03 18:12:25.000000000 +0200
+++ /etc/systemd/system/memcached.service   2015-03-02 16:44:27.486188508 +0200
@@ -5,6 +5,6 @@
 [Service]
 User=memcached
-# Remove '-l 127.0.0.1' to listen on all addresses
-ExecStart=/usr/bin/memcached -l 127.0.0.1
+RuntimeDirectory=memcached
+ExecStart=/usr/bin/memcached -s /run/memcached/socket 
 Restart=always
```

See Also:

- [`man memcached`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached) for options you can to pass to memcached.
- [`man systemctl`, edit command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#edit%20UNIT%E2%80%A6)

Answer (score -1):

You were close, it is in

/etc/php/conf.d/

Comment: Ah, this is the config dir for php, not the config for memcached.